# Linqpad 7 gives CS1705 on System.Runtime

Tags: linqpad

I have a console application developed using Visual Studio, targeting .NET 7.0.
I have a LinqPad script in which I reference the compiled dll (so I can use the many useful classes and methods in the app).
When I try to run the LinqPad query, I get the error

> CS1705 Assembly 'Hub' with identity 'Hub, Version=1.1.73.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime,
> Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime'
> with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Why is LinqPad 7 using System.Runtime V6.0.0.0, and how can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .NET dropdown on the toolbar, make sure that you choose **.NET 7**. It sounds like you're choosing .NET 6.

Note that if it's set to **Auto**, LINQPad will apply the global default setting. You can change the default setting in Edit | Preferences > Query.

Comment: Duh! Thanks for pointing out the obvious thing I missed! Never noticed that option before.